# How to make a call through Bluetooth on an another phone?

Tags: bluetooth, call, android-bluetooth, phone-call, ios-bluetooth

I have a cheap smartphone that can make calls, I also have an iPhone 12 which cannot make calls because it takes a hefty fee to make a phone support sim card where i live.

Can I make calls through iPhone 12 by connecting it to the cheap smartphone via Bluetooth?

the same way one can make calls through their smart watch.